Как заставить спарку читать float, у которой разделитель запятая?
Сейчас спарка при загрузке файлов воспринимает 1.02 как float, а 1,02 как string. Мне нужно чтобы она воспринимала и то, и другое, как float в независимости точка как делиметр стоит или запятая. Облазил параметры здесь https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties
Ничего не нашел. Может подскажите, кто знает?

В каком формате файл? CSV, parquet, ...?

Файл в формате CSV

У Спарка нет настроек на этот счёт https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-csv.html
Могу только посоветовать принудительно читать эту колонку как текст, делать замену запятых на точки, а потом уже конвертировать в float.
